# Reload partial code with Werkzeug reloader

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, reload, werkzeug

I have a python Flask app using blueprints and socketio that loads a big model (5GB) into memory before starting the app, like so:

**launcher.py**

```
import app
from model import load_model

if __name__ == "__main__":
    load_model()
    app.main()
```

**app.py**

```
from app import app, socketio

def main():
    socketio.run(app, port = 5000)
```

**model.py**

```
model = None

def load_model():
    global model
    if model is None:
        model = load_bigass_model_from_external_source() #this takes roughly 40 minutes

def get_model():
    return model
```

and then in my views I can call:

**views.py**

```
from model import get_model

@blueprint.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def home():
        print get_model()
```

Now this all works fine, except when I start changing code. Werkzeug reloads (which is fine by itself), however it also loads my model again. Loading the model takes about 40 minutes so you can see how this is not very desirable.

I want to know if there is any way to let Werkzeug reload everything else, but keep the model in memory if it has loaded once.

Comment: Have you tried to store the big model in a tmpfs and load it from there?